# How to set a custom font for a spinner?

Tags: android

Is there anyway to set a custom font or color for the selected item in a Spinner? For example, I open the spinner and click a priority of "High". I'm my layout containing the spinner, I would like to see the word "High" in red or a custom font.

I can't seem to obtain the textview to make the necessary change. I always obtain a NullPointerException if I typecast the spinner.getSelectedView() to textview and attempt to set the color. any ideas? thanks in advance!

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing with no success. I have just tried inflating the spinner text resource but that didn't work. ... A possible solution can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901231/how-to-change-font-style-for-spinner-item

Answer (score 1):

You are the one who tells Android the "font or color for the selected item in a Spinner". This comes from the layout resource you pass into the `SpinnerAdapter` you give to the `Spinner`. If you do not like the layout you are presently using, change the layout. If you are using a layout provided by Android, copy it from your SDK (`$ANDROID_HOME/platforms/$VERSION/data/res/`) into your project, change it, then refer to your local layout rather than the system-supplied one.

Answer (score 0):

hmm I can't seem to reply to to your post. I shouldve created an account first before I posted this question. Well, I can probably change the adapter to use a different layout resource, but that seems a bit cumbersome. There isn't a way to dynamically set it in the code? Like I said, I tried to setTypeface for the textview in my customlayout, but I just get a null pointer exception.