# How to change font style for spinner item

Tags: android, spinner

I have a spinner with items, populated via ArrayAdapter. I want to change font style for some (not for all) of spinner items, both for spinner's combobox and listbox. I guess that I need to subclass something, but I don't understand what. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok I got it.

1. Subclass ArrayAdapter and override getView and getDropDownView.
2. In those methods, call super.getView or super.getDropDownView and save returned value.
3. Set Typeface for view returned at (2) (thx Sameer Segal).

Comment: Can you provide your sample code. Bcoz I am stuck up in here.

Comment: Thats a good approach.. but i am trying the same for Cursor Adapter.. Have you got any idea about the Cursor Adapter...

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply fonts (typeface) to the TextViews of the layouts. Extract them through R.id.* or by supplying your own custom layout

Comment: You mean I have to create my own layout instead of using simple_spinner_item and simple_spinner_dropdown_item? But how can I do that for specific spinner items? E. g. I am doing _adTo.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); so if I will change it to my_italic_layout, every item will be italic.

Comment: If you are wondering about how to do it for the specific spinner items, Do this:
Check the incoming position parameter in the getView() and use it to target specific spinner items.