# Change style of Spinner

Tags: android, layout, spinner

I tried to change style of my multi choice spinner. I can change background of spinner but I can't change text colour and button background. Here Is my code:
styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/CustomDialogTheme</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/CustomDialogTheme</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/CustomDialogTheme</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/CustomDialogTheme</item>
</style>
<style name="CustomDialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:bottomBright">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:bottomDark">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:bottomMedium">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:centerBright">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:centerDark">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:centerMedium">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:fullBright">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:fullDark">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:topBright">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:topDark">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/blue</item>
</style>
```

And now, my spinner looks like:
[image]

I want to change text colour (`<item name="android:textColor">@color/blue</item>` doesn't work) and button background and checkbox colour. Is there any way to do this without defining own LayoutInflater ([Why does LayoutInflater ignore the layout_width and layout_height layout parameters I've specified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026926/making-sense-of-layoutinflater/5027921#5027921)) or creating subclass of array adapter([How to change font style for spinner item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901231/how-to-change-font-style-for-spinner-item))?

Answer (score 0):

You can see my github projects. I think this will help you too much.

[Custom Spinner](https://github.com/iamsarker/android-apps/tree/master/CustomSpinner)

[Custome Checkbox](https://github.com/iamsarker/android-apps/tree/master/CustomCheckBox)